# Why does the STL overload their constructors with/without allocator argument?

Tags: c++, constructor, stl, allocator

in `std::vector`, why does the stl overload the constructors like that:

```
vector( const vector& other );
vector( const vector& other, Allocator& a );
```

Why not just do this?

```
vector( const vector& other, Allocator& a = Allocator() );
```

Edit:

Since rvalues can't bind to a non const lvalue, then this can be done instead:

```
vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& a = Allocator() );
```

Comment: Because a non const lvalue ref cannot be bound to a temporary so `Allocator& a = Allocator()` won't work.

Comment: Perhaps because the first overload uses the same allocator of the passed vector, and the second for a specific allocator?

Comment: you still can pass your own if you do it like that `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& a = Allocator() );`, isn't it?

Comment: Where do you see these overloads?  Per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) the overload is `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc );`

Comment: @NathanOliver https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: @Zaki Even if you were to use a const lvalue ref then that would make `vector(vec)` to be **ambiguous** as the compiler wouldn't know which one of the above two constructors to use. See my edit.

Comment: @Zaki Which number overload are you looking at?

Comment: @NathanOliver Consider the copy constructor for example, why would you overload it like that: `vector( const vector& other ); ` and `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc );` while doing the following will be fine and save repetitive code: `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

Comment: The first form constructs the new vector using a copy of the allocator of the original.   The second form constructs the new vector using the specified allocator, which may differ from the allocator of the original, instead.     Incidentally, the constructors that accept an allocator argument do it by `const` reference, not non-`const` reference.

Comment: @Zaki I get that, I asked because your Q has `vector( const vector& other, Allocator& a );`, which is not the same as what you commented and what it is with `vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc );`

Comment: @NathanOliver that was a mistake on my part, I edited my question after jason pointed out that rvalues can't be bound to non-const references

Comment: The problem is that your question is fundamentally misleading. It implies the allocator parameter is non-const, whereas @NathanOliver is pointing out there is _no such constructor_ where that is the case. Since the use of custom allocators is not all that common, it's a very easy mistake to just take your word that this parameter is a lvalue reference, and then try to answer accordingly. I fell into that trap also, before actually checking the documentation.

Comment: @Zaki - In addition to the other answers, using a parameter like `const Allocator& a = Allocator() ` adds an additional requirement that the allocator actually has a default constructor, something the library tries to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allocator parameter allows the copy to use a specified allocator. The standard provides both constructors because they have fundamentally different properties.

The version with no allocator parameter will make a copy using the *same* allocator as `other`. Whereas the version with a specified allocator will make a copy using *that* allocator. Your suggestion of providing a default allocator makes distinguishing between these two versions impossible.

Here's what the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) says:

`vector(const vector& other)` :

> Copy constructor. Constructs the container with the copy of the contents of `other`.
>
> > The allocator is obtained as if by calling `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction( other.get_allocator())`

`vector(const vector& other, const Allocator& alloc)` :

> Constructs the container with the copy of the contents of `other`, using `alloc` as the allocator.
>
> > The template parameter `Allocator` is only deduced from the first argument while used in class template argument deduction.

Answer (score 0):

> Why not just do this?
>
> ```
> vector( const vector& other, Allocator& a = Allocator() );
> ```

Because a non const lvalue ref cannot be bound to a temporary so `Allocator& a = Allocator()` won't work.

---

**Edit**

> Since rvalues can't bind to a non const lvalue, then this can be done instead:
>
> ```
> vector( const vector& other, const Allocator& a = Allocator() );
> ```

Even if you were to use a const lvalue ref then that would make `vector(vec)` to be **ambiguous** as the compiler wouldn't know which one of the above two constructors to use.

Comment: Then why don't just use a const lvalue for the allocator and set a default value for it, instead of overloading all constructors like they do?

Comment: @Zaki Also note that the call `vector(vec)` would be ambiguous as the compiler wouldn't know which of the constructors to choose.

Comment: I tried this: `template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class Entity
{
public:
    using allocator_type = A;
    const char* name;

    Entity(const allocator_type& a = A())
    : name("default")
    {
        std::cout << "CONSTRUCTED\n";
    }

};` when instantiating the entity, no error was produced `Entity<int> e;
    Entity<int, std::allocator<int>> e1(std::allocator<int>());`